# opencv giving camera pose - rvec and tvec - with mismatched coordinate system

Tags: opencv, camera-calibration, coordinate-transformation

I need to find the pose (rotation matrix + translation vector) for a camera, and for that I am using `cv2.solvePnP()`, but the results I get from photos don't match.

In order to debug, I created (with numpy) a "debugging 3d scene" composed of some object points (four corners of a square), some camera points (focal point, principal point and four corners of the virtual projection plane) and parameters (focal distance, initial orientation).

Then, I construct a general rotation matrix by multiplying three axis rotation matrices, apply this general rotation to the camera (`numpy.dot()`), project the object points in the virtual projection plane (line-plane intersection algorithm), and calculate the in-plane 2D coordinates (point-line distance) to the projection plane axes.

After doing this (objectpoints to imagepoints via rotationmatrix), I feed the imagepoints and the objectpoints to `cv2.Rodrigues(cv2.solvePnP(...))` and get a matrix "not quite identical" to the one I used, only because of transposition and some elements with opposite signal (negative vs. positive), respecting this relation:

```
solvepnp_rotmatrix = my_original_matrix.transpose * [ 1  1  1] 
                                                    [ 1  1 -1] 
                                                    [-1 -1  1]
```

Although the rotation matrix mismatch is "solveable" with this hack, the TRANSLATION VECTOR gives coordinates that don't make sense to me.

I suspect there are mismatches between my 3D model (handedness, axes orientation, order of rotations) and the model used by opencv:

- I use OpenGL-like coordinate system (X increases to the right, Y increases upwards, and Z increases toward the observer;
- I applied the rotations in the order that made more sense to me (all right-handed, first around global Z, then around global X, then around global Y);
- The image plane is between object and camera focal point (virtual projection plane, instead of real/CCD);
- The origin of my image plane (virtual CCD) is lower-left corner (Xpix increases to the right, Ypx increases upwards.

My questions are:

Given that the terms of the rotation matrix are identical, only transposed and with different signal in some terms, is it possible that I am confusing some of `openCV` conventions (handedness, order of rotations, axis direction)? And how can I discover which one(s)?

Also, is there a way to relate my handmade translation vector to the tvec returned by `solvePnP`? (of course, ideally, the best would be to make the coordinate systems to match, in the first place).

Any help will be most welcome!

Comment: Why don't you construct your general rotation matrix with Rodrigues in the first place?  If all the conversions from rotation vector to rotation matrix happen inside opencv then you only need to worry about one set of conventions.  If that solves the problem then we know exactly where the problem lies (rotation order) otherwise it is elsewhere.